# Object fixed in div, but relative to JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div. Let's call it "Main_Card". "Main_Card" has some texts inside of it and  has an icon, that OnClick move this "Main_Card" and everything inside of it WITH icon itself. Now here is the problem. I need to have this icon's `position: relative;` (or absolute), but I also need to have Main_Card's `overflow-y: auto;`, cause of text may be long for some screens, so users can scroll it.

Here is the problem. When content of Main_Card has to be scrolled, it scrolls text properly, BUT it scroll also that icon. But I can't set icon's `position: fixed;`, cause it's also fixed to whole page, not only in Main_Card.

Can I somehow set icon "unscrollable"? Thanks, have a nice day!

Comment: What about setting `position: absolute` for the icon?

Comment: Nope. Does not work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hfzwq42g/ here is an example I just created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to see the code, because the question is not clear without it.

If I understand it right, just set overflow property to the text container.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  
}

.card-text {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-icon">
   </div>
  <p class="card-text">
    Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.
     Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.
     Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text. Some long text.
    
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://hdesign.comehere.cz/ you can see here, when u click on first card, card will slide in. When you scroll content, arrow will scroll too.

Comment: You have broken structure. Use the following: .card with two children .card-content(put all content inside this block, and apply overflow auto directly to this block) and .card-arrow(with position absolute and all necessary styles). Look at the structure in my example. One container with 2 children. In your solution its kinda messy =)

Comment: Yess! That's work in offline, thanks, I'll upload it later :)

Answer (score 0):

## Element fixed relative to parent using CSS only:

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:auto;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  background:#eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div i{
  position:fixed;
  /*NEVER ASSIGN TOP LEFT RIGHT BOTTOM PROPERTIES! */
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
div p{height:400px;border:4px dashed blue;} /*just to force scrollbars*/
```

```html
<div>
  <i></i>  
  <p></p>
</div>
```

*position* `fixed`, as soon you add a *left, right, top, bottom* will be related to the **viewport** instead to the **parent** element.
As long you don't touch those properties you can trick the browser to play nice with your desires.

Comment: Why do you say never assign top, left, right and bottom properties? What is wrong with that?

Comment: @LelioFaieta for the lazy ones http://jsbin.com/favowo/1/edit?html,css,output  and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thanks. I'm not lazy but css is not my cup of tea at all and I try to learn from who is more experienced :)

Comment: @LelioFaieta Well, I am lazy! So a *destructable* demo is always welcome :D